# Is a synchronous void method with Func<Task> or Func<Task<T>> arguments practically useful?

Tags: c#

I am teaching async-await keyword to my friends and up to now I gave them some examples as follows.

```
static async Task Do(Func<Task> job)
{
    // some algorithm depends on job parameter.
    await job();
}
```

I think this example is practically useful in many scenarios.

## Question

Is there any usefulness of having void methods with arguments of type `Func<Task>` or `Func<Task<T>>`? As far as I think, it does make sense for this kind of method to exist because blocking asynchronous methods are not recommended. Any comments are always welcome!

Comment: `static Task Do(Func<Task> job) { return job(); }`? `return DoSomethingElse(job)`?

Comment: "*The following does not seem to be useful IMHO.*" -- it's about as useful as `await job()`... The assumption is that other work is done before/after calling `job()`, regardless of whether the `Task` returned by `job()` is awaited or not.

Comment: The second executes the `job` funcion and returns the result. Nothing more/less

Comment: I've written methods which take a `Func<Task> job` and run the job on another thread. The method may or may not return its own `Task`, but it won't be `async`.

Comment: Your void-returning method might not be synchronous. It might do something like sending `job` to another thread.

Comment: @ArtificialOdorlessArmpit No, I never said you would use `job().Wait()`

Comment: The `Task` might end up being used with `ContinueWith`, or it might be awaited in an `async void` method, or perhaps it's completely ignored (as the `Task` returned from `Task.Run` often is), or maybe it's put in a queue and a consumer thread later awaits it.

Comment: @canton7: Sorry, I cannot grasp what you just explained without some code. Could you post the simplest code as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any usefulness of having void methods with arguments of type `Func<Task>` or `Func<Task<T>>`?

Yes. It would be a method that synchronously does something with that delegate. It would not execute the delegate directly.

One example that comes to mind is a kind of `Add` method for a queue of asynchronous work to do. The delegate would be executed elsewhere, in the "queue runner" code. Adding a delegate to the queue would be a synchronous operation, even though the delegate itself is asynchronous. [Here's an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.queuebackgroundworkitem?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_Hosting_HostingEnvironment_QueueBackgroundWorkItem_System_Func_System_Threading_CancellationToken_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, having non-asynchronous methods executing delegates can be useful, for example the [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) queries provided by .Net.

Sometimes you want the application to block until a specific result has been returned by the callee.

Let's take the [List.ForEach(Action)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=netframework-4.8) method for example.

(NOTE: This is **NOT** the actual implementation is it would be in .Net!)

```
public void ForEach(Action<T> action) {
    if (action is default(Action<T>))
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(action), "Action must not be null!");

    foreach (var element in this) {
        // Execute provided action (delegate)
        action(T);

    }
}
```

In this case, you want the loop to run synchronously, because of thread-safety for example.

---

Another example would be the `public static System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource> (this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource,bool> predicate);` method, which would also run synchronously, for thread safety reasons and so your results are returned as expected.

You can also always call the methods from a separate thread (or async method) if required. Most console applications run synchronously, as there is no GUI that needs to be responsive.

---

**EDIT**

Another example of synchronous methods with Func as the parameter would be a console application. Say you're implementing a console application with a library dependency (which you have no control over). This library only exposes tasks.
In a console application you generally don't use/need asynchronous applications as there's no GUI that can block and/or your application should only continue after the user has given input.

```
// External method returning a Task
public Task<int> DoFooAsync(object myParam);

public bool ParseMyFoo(Func<Task<int>> myTask) {
    var result = myTask().Result;

    if (result == 0xbadbeef || result == 0xf00dbabe) {
        Console.WriteLine("Schrödingers takeaway");
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine("Assesment: {0}", ParseMyFoo(DooFooAsync(Console.ReadLine()));
}
```

Comment: Why did you take an example with  `Action` rather than `Func<Task>` or `Func<Task<T>>`?

Comment: They're essentially the same, it was just an example of an implementation. I added a second example using a Func<T> at the bottom. 
I'll add a further code.

Comment: @canton7 Sorry, you're right. Forgot the Result property.

Comment: `Main` will not be able to catch any possible exceptions thrown in `ParseMyFoo` so  this example is too bad for teaching purposes.